# How do I handle the situation when I allow safe external HTML elements but they are not valid, thus still breaking my webpage?

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I fetch HTML blobs from external sources, for example RSS feeds, and display in my little localhost web control panel.

For security, I use `strip_tags` on this content and only allow a small number of "safe" HTML elements, such as `<p>` and `<div>`.

Up until today, it has worked as expected.

But today, I got such a HTML blob which had an error: it contained a `<div>` but not `</div>`, meaning that it ended up messing with my own webpage.

Simply disallowing `<div>` is not a solution as it would make the content a mess, and of course they could do the same thing with `<p>` as well or any other allowed element.

I do have a means to validate HTML strings locally, but it takes like two seconds each time, so it's going to add a lot of extra slow-downs. However, if no other solution can be found, I will do this. (That is, if it's not valid, I just strip all HTML elements and let it become a mess/blob rather than breaking my webpage.)

I should of course have predicted that sooner or later, some external source from where I fetch data would have broken HTML. It's a wonder it didn't happen earlier. Still, there is no obvious solution which preserves some kind of structure/markup and is guaranteed to not mess with my page.

I do use an iframe for displaying HTML e-mails, but there are problems with that approach and it basically makes the page annoying to navigate and deal with, so I try to avoid that "solution" for this.

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by 'validate HTML'? Is it capable of fixing broken markup? Your question is hard to answer because you haven't specified any design goals. Start by formulating what is acceptable, and where you'll draw the line. Also, relying on `strip_tags()` to make imported markup "safe" is not a good idea. This markup will happily slip through: `<div onmouseenter="alert('Hi');">Allowed tag with inline scripting</div>`.

Comment: IIRC html-tidy can "fix" incorrect html

Comment: @RoAchterberg By "validate HTML", I mean "validate HTML". No, it's not capable of fixing it. I didn't say or imply that. And feel free to tell me a superior alternative to `strip_tags` since it lets inline JavaScript through (which I have actually feared).

Comment: Take it easy there with the tone my good buddy. I will again suggest to think about design goals first, and implementations later. What would be 'superior' is going to be up to you in the first place. Are you only crawling from a few fixed sources? Are you able to recognize patterns in their output? In which case I would personally just try to veer around the issue by adapting to their patterns.

Comment: @RoAchterberg I would in turn appreciate a far less condescending tone from you, "buddy". You seem utterly unwilling to actually read my question and insist on second-guessing me, even though I provided all information and a clear question. I don't think you want to help.

Comment: @user379490, take it down a few notches, friend. Instead of talking back you could recognize somebody's efforts to better understand your vague question. And when insights are offered to you (for free!) that potentially save you from getting hacked, then you better just be grateful!